# New line constant in the url breaks the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am using ASP.NET and c# to build my website.
I am facing some issues with newline constant in the url.

Here is my Url

```
http://localhost/TestProject/Login/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=http://google.com?search=Software+Engineer%0ASalesforce.com
```

which contains a new line constant. (%0A)

In my code i am decoding the url to get some parameter, so i am using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode to decode the url and later after that, i am appending some session id to the url and redirecting the same.

Since the Url contains new line constant, it breaking my page and throws an exception
**Value does not fall within the expected range.**

if i remove the new line constant from the url its working fine as expected.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: Could you show us the stack trace? Where does the code throw an exception?

Comment: Why not just strip newlines out after decoding the URL?

Comment: I cannot strip url, and this is a returnurl which i need to take the user to that url.